# Why lazy loading sections creates overflow_x

Tags: javascript, sass

Hello I have a problem I am trying to make my page RWD but the problem is it creates overflow_x when sections are loaded by interSectionObserver, and it causes that positioning on page dies but when it reaches end of the page, everything is fixed. More code can be found on my github but I am not sure do I have permission to paste it.

CSS

```
.section {
   transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
}
.hidden-section {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(7rem);
}
```

JS:

```
        
        _revealSection() {
                const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
                const options = {
                    root: null,
                    threshold: 0.15,
                    rootMargin: "0px",
                }
        
                const showSection = ((entries, observer) => {
                    const [entry] = entries;
                    if (!entry.isIntersecting) return 
                    entry.target.classList.toggle('hidden-section')
                    observer.unobserve(entry.target)
                    
                })
        
                const sectionFadeIn = new IntersectionObserver(showSection, options);
        
                sections.forEach(sec => {
                    sec.classList.add('hidden-section')
                    sectionFadeIn.observe(sec)
                } )
            }

HTML:

    <section class="section" id="section--5">
                <div class="contact">
                    <h1 class="contact__header">Are you ready for an new experience?</h1>
                    <button class=" modal-button contact__button" data-but="4">contact us</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add some relevant HTML as well. We can't troubleshoot without it. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It might just be me but what is RWD?

Comment: The problem with HTMl is that I should put the whole file because it is about sections, but sure i will try put some.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was in html and body tag.

```
html, body {
width: 100;
overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```